# Fetch items of a nested list using lambda expression

Tags: python

Is it possible to fetch using a lambda expression.

**Structure of nested list:**

An overview `[sent1, sent2, ..., sentn]` for `sentn = [(word1, ne),...,(wordn,ne)]`

e.g.,

```
data = [[('EU', 'ORG'), ('rejects', 'O'), ('German', 'MISC'), ('call', 'O'), ('to', 'O'), ('boycott', 'O'),\
  ('British', 'MISC'), ('lamb', 'O'), ('.', 'O')],\
 [('BRUSSELS', 'LOC'), ('1996-08-22', 'O')]]
```

Suppose I'd like to extract words for each sentence, obtaining

**Desired Output:**

```
[['EU', 'rejects', 'German', 'call', 'to', 'boycott', 'British', 'lamb', '.'], ['BRUSSELS', '1996-08-22']]
```

**My code:**

```
sents = []
for s in data:
    words = [w[0] for w in s]
    sents.append(words)
```

This code works, just wondered if there's a way using lambda expression to perform a similarly task.

Comment: Where did `['Peter', 'Blackburn']` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using lambda expression, but using a nested list comprehension:

```
sents = [[w[0] for w in s] for s in data]
```

Is this what you had in mind?